# Stack bootstrap blocks from 3x2 to 2x3 format

Tags: grid, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the footer of my website I have 6 blocks.
On small screens I want them stacked as 2x3

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="aboutme">
                <div class="headline"><h2><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>About me</h2></div>
                <div class="box">
                    <img class="portrait" src="assets/img/portrait.jpg" />
                    testje
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="headline"><h2><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Recent blog posts</h2></div>
            <div class="box">

            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="headline"><h2><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Recent projects</h2></div>
            <div class="box"></div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="headline"><h2><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Books</h2></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="headline"><h2><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Stay connected</h2></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="headline"><h2><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Drop a line</h2></div>
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do I need to start a new row or can I rely on the stacking process if column number exceeds 12?

At this moment it is stacked as follows:

```
[][]
  []
[][]
  []
```

So it needs a sort of float fix I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to start a new row. If you remove the dividing row you should get 3 columns of 2, and then 2 columns of 3 on smaller screens. A single columns on smallest screens.

http://www.bootply.com/121418

Comment: Well bootstrap docs mentioned that you need to add up max 12 columns.

Comment: The problem was a margin rule in my CSS file for the image inside the about me box.

I still need a margin setting for that box, how do I avoid the stacking effect?